# What does "sagged" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

What does **sagged** mean when we talk about someone who committed suicide by putting rod across two doors?

> "The rod was flat on one side, and both doors **sagged**, dragging and
>   then resting upon the floor".

Answer (score 2):

### The door does not hang straight in its frame:

[image: Sagging Door]